# How do I create a tilt-shift photography effect?

Tags: tilt-shift, effect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to create a tilt-shift photograph?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-tilt-shift-photograph)
>   [How to get a miniature effect on pictures?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/how-to-get-a-miniature-effect-on-pictures)

I have seen in different places the tilt-shift photography effect, and have never been able to recreate it on my own. What is the secret to these kinds of pictures? Does it only work with classic trains, or is it some setting on your camera?

P.S. Does anyone know of any other tags I could put on this question?

Comment: Also [How to get a miniature effect on pictures?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/how-to-get-a-miniature-effect-on-pictures)

Comment: Also pretty much everything existing under [tag:tilt-shift]. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is some software that will replicate the effect, especially special effects camera apps for smart phones, but the only true way to achieve the effect is with a very expensive tilt shift lens for a dslr.

There is a cheaper alternative in the form of a lens baby (also for a dslr), which will give you a similar effect at the expense of quality.

Comment: They need not be "very expensive". Russian- or Ukranian-made ones can be had for a very reasonable price in various mounts; I have one myself.