# Is there a way to create a tilt-shift photography effect without changing aperture?

Tags: aperture, effect, tilt-shift, camera-settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a miniature effect on pictures without special equipment?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/how-to-get-a-miniature-effect-on-pictures-without-special-equipment)

I recently asked a [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21732/how-do-i-create-a-tilt-shift-photography-effect) that was closed, and this question is *not the same*. I am still trying to create different tilt-shift photographs, and I'm wondering is the only way to create a tilt-shift effect by changing aperture?

Comment: Can you clarify how that question was not the same? From all the information you provided, they appear identical.

Comment: **Yes**. *None* of the [ways to do tilt-shift photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-tilt-shift-photograph) require you to change aperture.

Comment: _This_ question appears a bit strange in context, then, because the answers to the other two questions explain several ways to get this effect, and as Imre says, none of them are about changing aperture.

Comment: I've heard that one way to create a tilt-shift effect is to use a very small aperture.

Comment: That would work, but only *with a tilt-shift lens*, and using the small aperture is not an absolute requirement then.

Comment: Okay, then how do I create the effect *without* one of those lenses?

Comment: Tilt-shift lenses provide several effects; e.g. miniature effect, perspective correction, mirror clearing, infinite depth of field. In any case, you can find the ways to achieve them in the answers to [question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-tilt-shift-photograph) already referenced to you.

Comment: Or this question http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/how-to-get-a-miniature-effect-on-pictures-without-special-equipment

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways you can achieve the tilt-shift effect

- freehand the lens unmounted
- Get a lensbaby (http://www.lensbaby.com/lenses-composer.php)
- Get a tilt-shift lens (http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Camera-Lenses/Perspective-Control/index.page)