# Tilt-shift miniature effect from lens versus post-processing miniature effect

Tags: software, post-processing, tilt-shift

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get a miniature effect on pictures without special equipment?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/how-to-get-a-miniature-effect-on-pictures-without-special-equipment)

Miniature faking can be done in post-processing using in-camera software, other software, or sites like [tiltshiftmaker.com](http://tiltshiftmaker.com). Are there any major limitations to this approach compared with using a tilt-shift lens? Can you achieve all the miniature effects that you get with a tilt-shift lens with a software?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [What's the best way to create a tilt-shift photograph?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/whats-the-best-way-to-create-a-tilt-shift-photograph) and [How to get a miniature effect on pictures without special equipment?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15929/how-to-get-a-miniature-effect-on-pictures-without-special-equipment) ? Do these answer your questions?

Answer (score 2):

Technically the best way to do a fake miniature is in post production by creating a full depth map of the scene. The online apps apply a simple linear depth map which can look fake as the top of an object can appear a different depth from the base.

Tilt shift lenses provide a more realistic blur, however the amount and of blur is still not consistent with a real miniature scene.

Ultimately it's up to the photographer which they prefer the look of, and which they would rather do - more work taking the photo, or more work in post production.

Answer (score 0):

Personally i think its quite obvious when its a digital effect as opposed to a real image, raw through a lens.

2 reasons:
1: The 'blur' is digital, it doesnt know the distance of the actual subjects - therefore it applies a set blur to the frame varied by its vertical orientation in the frame. 
A real lens blurs more distant objects more than closer ones, no matter where they are in the frame.

2: these filters often apply a LOT of saturation to the shot - which looks un-natural, however i think thats the point. 
|

Also,
A real tilt-shift lens in in-fact designed to keep angled objects IN focus!