# Are there cameras which have only bodies, and no default attached lenses?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

Do the cameras exist which have only bodies, and no default attached lenses?

Example this camera has a default lens attached:
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/B004J3V90Y/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004J3V90Y)

I would like to have a camera with absolutely no lens at all. Do such things exist?

Comment: Usually the high-end bodies don't ever have a kit-offer.

Comment: Maybe it depends on the market, if they sell cameras in body-only version. Here in Finland you can buy just about any dslr camera without a lens.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. You're looking for "Body Only" offerings. The same camera without any lens:

[Canon T3i Body Only](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004M170YC)

Note that you must have *something* to attach to (or at least [hold in front of](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8513/what-is-freelensing)) the camera; when used without any lens at all, the whole image will be a total blur with absolutely no focus whatsoever:

[image: sample image taken without lens]

For comparison, same scene taken with an old 58mm lens at f/2:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have to ask them, there's no reason to buy a kit lens each time you upgrade your camera,

Comment: When clicking on the cameras, you'll see that most of the prices are "Body Only", while D3100 is with a 18-55mm lens.

Comment: Your comparison is hilarious and awesome.

Comment: I can't believe you included a image shot without a lens on, that is badass!

Comment: Do note that it is a good idea to get it with the kit lens though. Generally cheaper. High-end bodies mostly don't even have a kit lens option. usually body only.

Answer (score 1):

Every DSLR model can be purchased as only body. Normally the package with a default kit lens have good value as you can save some money over buying them separately, therefore recommended in most cases. But if you already own all the lenses you need, you should buy [only the body](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004J3V90Y).

Comment: This isn't strictly true. Many entry-level cameras are only offered in kit form. Also, due to some quirk of economics, the entry-level Pentax camera _with_ kit lens is often weirdly _cheaper_ than the body-only offering.

Comment: mattdm: no necessarily, as I bought my K-x, the body only was very slightly cheaper :-) However, I would never get new 18-55 AF lens for such money, so I had no reason to buy body only (was my first DSLR). ;-)